# Phrase: What does" no wish to all" mean?

Tags: phrases

Have you ever heard about the phrase "no  wish to all"?
Can you help me explain it?
The context is a man having conversation with his friend. He's complaining about receiving marketing texts on his mobile phones which made him irritating.
He said " They tend to come from the companies that I know nothing about, trying to sell me things of **no wish to all**."

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to provide the context in which you heard the phrase?

Comment: Hi, I just edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: That phrasing sounds like a mistake to me. Are you sure you didn't misunderstand what he said? It would have made sense to say, "...trying to sell me things I've no wish to buy" or "...I've no wish to own" (which sounds similar to what you think the phrase was).

Comment: oh yeah, maybe it's "no wish to own". It would be more accurate. As this is a practicing listening part, it cannot be "no wish to all" with no meaning at all.  It's my mistake. Thank you so much.

Comment: It sounds to me like a misheard “no wish at all”, which means something like “completely no wish”.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your reply. I think " no wish at all " is quite right in this case. However, the word in the listening record is" no wish to.....". They used the word "to" so I think the word after it is "own" which is better than "all" which makes me confused.

Comment: I suspect that the phrase is "things I've no wish to own". But given it's a listening exercise (a) we can't answer without access to the source material; (b) we've already decided that [transcription requests are off-topic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10723/18696). This question conveniently gets around that by asking about a phrase which is a potential interpretation of the heard text, but here the answer is "You've almost certainly heard that wrong; the phrase makes no sense" and we can't really help any further than that.

Comment: I agree that you have probably misheard it but I wonder if you have misheard "no use at all" or "no use to me at all" and replaced 'use' with 'wish' because that's what you thought you'd heard.

Comment: Hi BoldBen, thanks for your reply. I am quite sure of the phrase "no wish" as I heard it clearly. if it is the case, it maybe " things I have no wish to own" as I consider the pronunciation of "I have" sounds like "of".

Comment: Thanks so much Andrew Leach. I have not looked for the transcript online but in the book, there's no transcript included.